# How to create sql server master key and certificate from C# code?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am able to create this from sql server execution following sql command but is there any way to execute this command using C# code ?

sql commands ...

```
USE master;
    CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'rajesh';
Go

Use Master
    BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'C:\Users\HP USER\Desktop\Encrypt\KEYs' 
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'rajesh'
GO 

Use Master
      CREATE CERTIFICATE mytestcert
      WITH SUBJECT = 'Mytestcertificate'

Use Master
    BACKUP CERTIFICATE mytestcert TO FILE = 'C:\Users\HP USER\Desktop\Encrypt\mytestcert.cer'
GO

CREATE DATABASE dbShop ;
GO  

USE dbShop
GO
CREATE DATABASE ENCRYPTION KEY 
  WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
  ENCRYPTION BY SERVER CERTIFICATE [mytestcert]
ALTER DATABASE test
  SET ENCRYPTION ON;
```

Comment: Why can't you just execute these commands from C# that same way you would execute any other SQL commands?

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but the [`Smo`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.aspx) namespaces seem to have several likely looking classes such as `MasterKey`.

Answer (score 0):

You could place your commands in a stored proc and then execute the stored proc from C#.

Comment: I don't have any database in sql server..completely new installation before attaching database to server i have to create certificate and key because database is protected by key and certificate so where to create stored procedure ? & also i am new user to sql server